# How to put a lambda expression in a variable and then pass it to a s/r

Tags: c#, lambda, parameter-passing

Sorry for this question: I am somehow new to lambda expressions.
I have a library and some functions and I want to pass the to execute some actions. Therefore I thought about putting some code in a lamba expression, associate it to a variable and the make it execute from the library s/r.
In short (pseudocode):

```
var1 = { ...code1...};
var2 = { ...code2...};
ExternalFunction(??? var1, ??? var2);


ExternalFunc(??? var1, ???var2)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Executing code 1");
  ???

  Console.WriteLine("Executing code 2");
  ???
}
```

Comment: Do you mean like: `Action var1 = () => { ...code1...};
Action var2 = () => { ...code2...};
ExternalFunction(var1, var2);` where the method is declared as `static void ExternalFunc(Action var1, Action var2) { Console.WriteLine("Executing code 1"); var1(); Console.WriteLine("Executing code 2"); var2(); }`. The type here, `Action`, is a delegate type whose signature is the empty list of parameters, and whose return type is `void`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what your code should do you will need a parameter of type `Action<T1, T2, ...>` or `Func<T1, T2, ...>`. However you cannot create your method so that it runs any arbitrary code, you have to provide a return-type and the parameters of course.

So if your code of block returns an int and expects a string you may write this:

```
Func<string, int> myFunc = x => Convert.ToInt32(x) + 1;

void ExternalFunc(Func<T1, T2> myFunc, T1 param) {
    var myInt = myFunc(param);
}
```

Now call it like this:

```
ExternalFunc(myFunc, "1");
```

However you cannot expect this code to run also:

```
Func<int> myOtherFunc = () => 1;
ExternalFunc(myOtherFunc)
```

because `myOtherFunc` must be of type `Func<T1, T2>`, not just `Func<T>` to be passed to `ExternalFunc`.

Moreover if your code-block should not return anything (`void`), use an `Action<...>` instead of `Func<...>`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's your standard documentation for lambdas:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

if you're looking for the type inference of a lambda, it's a Func. So the parameter text you're looking for is probably this:

```
public void youtExternalFunction(Func<> var1, Func<T, U> var2)
```